# C programming: Find the subtraction of two greatest numbers out of three

Tags: c

I'm starting to learn the c programming language and I have to write a program that subtracts two greatest numbers out of the three entered numbers. Can anyone help me with this?

Edit: Sorry, I still don't know how this site functions...

I know how to find the greatest number, but I'm not sure how to find the other one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, max;

     printf("Enter three numbers: ");
     scanf("%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
     max=a;
     if (max<b) {max=b;}
     if (max<c) {max=c;}
     printf("the greatest number is %d\n", max);


     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What did you try? This is not a "write this program for me"-service, it's about helping with questions about *your* code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to put some code in your question. Show us whay you've done already.

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't expect to get answers to questions like yours. Try this. The assumption is that you are dealing with positive integers only. If you need to consider negative integers as well, you can do it yourself. You should note that this is the not the best solution, there can be much more elegant ones.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numbers[3];
    printf("Enter number 1: \n");
    scanf("%d", &numbers[0]);

    printf("Enter number 2; \n");
    scanf("%d", &numbers[1]);

    printf("Enter number 3: \n");
    scanf("%d", &numbers[2]);

    printf("%d %d %d\n", numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]);

    int maximum_0 = 0;
    int maximum_1 = 0;

    int i;


    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > maximum_0) {
            maximum_0 = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > maximum_1 && numbers[i] < maximum_0) {
            maximum_1 = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Result: %d\n", (maximum_0 - maximum_1)); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really help me... :(

Comment: Please dont provide the whole bunch of code as answer. just inform the OP the part of solution to be altered.

Comment: @chloramphenicol, It does what you asked, why doesn't it help you? If you have other requirements than add them all to your question. Nobody here is psychic.

Comment: Thank you @Nurzhan I'll have to study this a little to fully understand it. I'm still new at this. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

//Here it is since you are beginner Without loops

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, max,min,result;
    printf("Enter three numbers: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    if(a>b)
    {
        if(a>c)
        {
            max=a;
            if(c>b)
                min=c;
            else
                min=b;

        }
        else
        {
            max=c;
            a=min;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(b>c)
        {
            max=b;
            if(a>c)
                min=a;
            else
                min=c;
        }
        else
        {
            max=c;
            min=b;
        }
    }
    result=max-min;
    printf("the greatest number is %d\n", result);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This was a little bit tricky to figure out, but with the right names of the variables, I've got it. Thank you!

Comment: @chloramphenicol Welcome and you can tick mark my solution as an answer !!

Comment: I did, but apparently I cannot have two correct answers, I  don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array and then use qsort to sort your values. The code below will do this for you. The order of the array will be such that the first element will have your smallest number and the last element your largest.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(const void* d1, const void* d2)
{
    int a = *(int*)d1;
    int b = *(int*)d2;

    if (a > b)return 1;
    if (b > a)return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int abc[3];

    printf("Enter three numbers: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &abc[0], &abc[1], &abc[2]);

    qsort(abc, 3, sizeof(int), sort);

    printf("%d\n", abc[2] - abc[1]);

    while (1){}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is too advanced for me now, but I will figure it out as I learn.